# Tetris Rotation without arrays

Tags: c++, objective-c, tetris

I am writing a Tetris Clone, it is almost done, except for the collisions. For example In order to move the Piece Z I use a method:

```
void PieceZ::movePieceDown()
{ 
  drawBlock (x1,y1++);
  drawBlock (x2,y2++);
  drawBlock (x3,y3++);
  drawBlock (x4,y4++);
}
```

and in order to rotate a Piece I use a setter (because coordinates are private). For rotation I use a 90 degree clockwise rotation matrix. For example if I want to move **(x1,y1)** and **(x2, y2)** is my origin, to get x and y of a new block:

```
newX = (y1-y2) + x2;
newY = (x2-x1) + y2 + 1;
```

That works to some extent, it starts out as:

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0
```

Then as planned it rotates to:

```
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

And then it rotates to Piece S:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

And then it just alternates between the second and the third stages.

My calculations are wrong but I can't figure out where, I just need a little hint.

Comment: To verify that transformation is correct rotate the origin block itself. The result should be that the block does not move. In your case `newX` remains `x2`, but `newY` becomes `y2 + 1`, instead of remaining `y2`.

Comment: Also, different coordinates should not exist in the same expression. Since you are rotating a piece then all values that affect `x` coord must be of `y` kind, and all that affect `y` must be `x` in nature.

Comment: The block you use as the origin, <x2,y2> is updated after you calculate <x1,y1>, but before you calculate <x3,y3> and <x4,y4>, so not all blocks are using the same origin coordinates.  You should save a copy of <x2,y2>, which will stay consistent throughout the entire transform calculation.

Comment: @Dialecticus Thank you very much for your suggestion, I will make sure to verify my epxression like that!

Comment: @ChristopherOicles That is exactly what my problem was, that is why I add 1 to the y coordinate because otherwise the blocks are not in place

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how it should go (somewhat):

- Determine where you want to rotate the piece (this could be the upper or lower corner or the center) and call it `origin`
- Calculate the new x `newX = y - origin.y;`
- Calculate the new y `newY = -x + origin.x;`

This should work (I got this idea from wikipedia and rotation matrixes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! It's clear that mathematically expressions are correct, but they don't work for me. As **ChristopherOicles** mentioned it is probably because my origin value always changes, because I am implementing it. But fixing it doesn't fix it at all. I guess I have to play with coordinates to figure it out.